# Problema con else básico de condicion en Java

Tags: java, condiciones, else

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class ejer1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int N;
        System.out.println("Inreoduzca su numero entero: ");
        N=sc.nextInt();
     if (N%2==0);{
        System.out.println("Par");
     }
        else{
        System.out.println("Impar");
    

        }
    }
}
```

He intenatdo hacer este jercicio y no puedo me da error en la linea 15 en el else el error dice: syntax error on token "else" delte this token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fijate que tenes un `;` de más cuando termina la condición del `if`

Debería ser:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ejer1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N;
        System.out.println("Inreoduzca su numero entero: ");
        N = sc.nextInt();
        if (N%2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Par");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Impar");
        }
    }
     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La estructura del if debe ser:

```
if (condicion){
   System.out.println("Par");
}else{
   System.out.println("Impar");
}
```

Revisa la documentaciòn oficial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

si escribes `;` indica que finaliza la instrucciòn por lo tanto no debes usarlo en el `if`, este serìa el còdigo, en realidad ya tenìas correctamente tu programa:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int N;
    System.out.println("Inreoduzca su numero entero: ");
    N=sc.nextInt();
    if (N%2==0){
       System.out.println("Par");
    }else{
       System.out.println("Impar");
    }
  }
}
```